# Append length in iso8583 using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, iso8583, jpos

I am using ISO8583 Sampler in JMeter for Sending ISO Messages, I need to append the length in  in hex of the total message divide by 2 at the beginning. I have read the documentation and i cannot find anything.

Git: https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-iso8583

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is, why do you need to manually perform that?

I believe you just need to select the proper channel in the [connection configuration](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-iso8583#iso8583-connection-configuration).

Depending on what you mean by "in hex" maybe `HEXChannel` which sends four ASCII bytes with the hex character or `NACChannel` which will send 2 bytes with the length, some people incorrectly call that hex when they are actually just 2 raw bytes.

Comment: Yes, I need to append HEXChannel of 2 raw bytes. I have set the connection configuration properly. It doesn't get appended to my message.

Comment: Are you sure what you need isn't `NACChannel`?

Comment: also, what do you mean it doesn't get appendend? where do you need to see it appended? is the channel's job to send the length, if it is not doing that, then you are having some more serious configuration problem. BTW, you won't see it in the request body tab since it is appended at send time.

Comment: I have resolved by changing it to NACChannel. But EMVTag is being parsed properly. 
My EMVtag value: 5F2A02058682027C008408A000000333010102950500000480009A032112079C01009F02060000005000009F03060000000000009F090200209F101307000103A0A812010A010000000000E687F6ED9F1A0205869F1E0832303136303232379F2608AE6E5109BE0223EB9F2701809F3303E0F8C89F34034203009F3501229F360201319F37048D2C4AE99F4104000010795F340101 
I need it to be send in LLLBIN. Any idea how might i solve it

Comment: I would try `<isofield id="55" length="999" name="RESERVED ISO" class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLBINARY"/>` for DE 55

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor), if you add it as a child of the ISO8583 Sampler you will be able to access the underlying class functions using [`sampler` shorthand](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy), in your case it will be [ISO8583Sampler](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-iso8583/blob/792263208c0981e21786f537e990cb0f8ff3be0a/src/main/java/nz/co/breakpoint/jmeter/iso8583/ISO8583Sampler.java), take a look at available methods, i.e. [getRequest()](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-iso8583/blob/792263208c0981e21786f537e990cb0f8ff3be0a/src/main/java/nz/co/breakpoint/jmeter/iso8583/ISO8583Sampler.java#L233) will give you an instance of [ISOMsg](http://jpos.org/doc/javadoc/org/jpos/iso/ISOMsg.html) and you can get/set the neccessary header/fields/whatever.